# My Blog page ( posts page ) theme isn't changing with the new theme

Tags: plugins, posts, themes, templates

I have changed my WordPress theme to [Raft](https://wordpress.org/themes/raft/) and the whole website changed its theme accordingly to my new theme but my post page which name is "Blogs" is still in its old theme which came with the default with the WordPress I install through the hosting website ([infinity free](https://www.infinityfree.net/)).

I don't know whats the problem I deleted the cache from the browser and reload the website multiple times but the blogs section is still the old theme. All the other pages of the websites are shaped according to the new theme except the blogs page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.  Is there a caching plugin active?  Is there caching at the hosting level?  Have you loaded the page in a private/incognito browser window?

Have you tried to completely remove the old theme?

What is the URL of the site and the blogs page?  I'd love to look at the response headers to see if there is anything there that would indicate what the issue is.